# SmartFox Server Facebook friends integration iOS

Tags: objective-c, facebook, ios6, xcode4.5, smartfoxserver

I am new to SmartFox server(iOS). I just started using tutorials (iOS).
I want to Integrate Facebook with SmartFox Server,  i want to Play my Game with my facebook friends. so is there any tutorial or sample code (iOS) ? for inviting facebook friends and play game. 
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the facebookid as the user sign on for smartfox and then check the users friends list on facebook to play with those users on smartfox.

For inviting facebook friends you can send them a private message or if you have a facebook app, you can send an invite through that.

[facebook ios-sdk challenge requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios-sdk-games/requests/)